# Is it ok to unset a var for a property not yet defined?

Tags: ant, build, ant-contrib

Say I have something like this in a `macrodef`:

```
<var name="someName" unset="true" />
<property name="someName" value="someValue" />
```

This seems to work, but is it a defined behavior to unset a var before it being set? I am new to ant and haven't find anything which documents this case.

Comment: "var" is not part of standard ANT. It's provided by the ant-contrib extension, see: http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html. This might help explain the difference with "property" which is a standard task. Properties in ANT are immutable and cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is ok to unset a variable (which is nothing more than a mutable property) if it is not set. Unsetting the variable boils down to removing an entry from a hash table that contains the list of properties. From the documentation of [`Hashtable#remove(Object key)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#remove(java.lang.Object)):

> Removes the key (and its corresponding value) from this hashtable. This method does nothing if the key is not in the hashtable.